# What does it mean to determine the savings over the most efficient fixed length code?

Tags: coding-theory

I have some information coding theory questions but I'm asked to determine the savings over the most efficient fixed length code, and I don't know what this means.  What is the "savings?" that the question is asking for?  Thank you for any help!
[exercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSWLl.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to look up and understand the definitions.  If you have $k$ different messages you might want to send, a fixed length code needs $\lceil \log_2 k\rceil$ bits.  Compression techniques will send frequent messages with fewer bits.  You should compare the average number of bits sent for a compressed message with the number of bits of a fixed length code.  The difference is the savings.  The result depends on the compression used and the probability distribution of the messages.